# ServiceStack OrmLite - pre and post execution

Tags: postgresql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We are using the awesome & fast OrmLite (ServiceStack) library as our microORM to connect to our PostgreSQL database.

We have [TDE](https://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM7-HoioPLAhWDrRoKHZNdCIYQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.enterprisedb.com%2Fpostgres-plus-edb-blog%2Fvibhor-kumar%2Fpostgres-and-transparent-data-encryption-tde&usg=AFQjCNGhHZ0PwH2Hs6jDavZdfoWYmbRG1w&sig2=QImwFUacdOlw8F_NY14dYA&bvm=bv.114733917,d.d2s) encryption enabled in our PostgreSQL database. To ensure that the relevant data is decrypted before we query, we need to execute the following:

```
Db.ExecuteSql(string.Format("SELECT pgtde_begin_session('{0}');", tdeKey));
```

and at the end:

```
Db.ExecuteSql("SELECT pgtde_end_session();");
```

Instead of inserting these into each of our RequestDto methods, can we instead ensure that these sql statements are executed before and after each call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using an [OrmLite Exec Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#exec-result-and-string-filters), with something like:

```
public class PgSqlSecureSessionFilter : OrmLiteExecFilter
{
    public override T Exec<T>(IDbConnection db, Func<IDbCommand, T> filter)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Execute("SELECT pgtde_begin_session(@tdeKey)", new { tdeKey });
            return base.Exec(db, filter);
        }
        finally {
            db.Execute("SELECT pgtde_end_session();");
        }
    }
}

OrmLiteConfig.ExecFilter = new PgSqlSecureSessionFilter();
```

Comment: thanks. Out of interest, where would you suggest to add the above code. In the main project or serviceinterface?

Comment: @MarkH It's just a static property that should be initialized on StartUp, i.e. together with `OrmLiteConnectionFactory`.

Comment: we noticed that the db.ExecuteSql is causing the exec filter to be called again (recursion).

Comment: @MarkH yeah it would do that for OrmLite APIs, can you try just Execute() which should use the embedded version of Dapper in the ServiceStack.OrmLite.Dapper namespace, otherwise you'll need to fallback to using raw ADO.NETs IDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()